# Prevent rounding of boxplot limits

Tags: r, boxplot

When creating a boxplot, my limits are automatically rounded up which results in not identifying an outlier. Is there a way to prevent rounding or manually changing the limits?

[image]

I've tried changing the xlim, but that's more for scale and not actual whisker limits

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but there are a few things you could do to improve it. (1) Please post information that will help us reproduce the problem in a **text format**: e.g. if you `dput(sort(flight$L401))`, we will be able to replicate your problem. (2) Can you say more precisely what you mean by rounding up?  Is it the difference between your computed thresholds and the results of `fivenum()` ?

Answer (score 1):

IQR calculates quantiles in one of nine user-selectable ways (see the *type* argument in `?quantile`). However, the box of boxplots is determined slightly differently (see `?boxplot.stats`).

You could either replace the boxplot stats with IQR or `fivenum` results:

```
my_boxplot <- boxplot(my_data)
my_boxplot$stats <- matrix(five_number_vector, , 1) ## replace with custom stats
my_boxplot$out <- outlier_vector ## replace with custom outliers

bxp(my_boxplot) ## plot the customized thing
```

... or stick with `boxplot`'s default notion of interquartiles and outliers.